# Equality of functions $f(x)=x^\frac{m}{n}$ and $g(x)= \sqrt[n]{x^m}$

Tags: functions, radicals

Are the functions $f(x)=x^\frac{m}{n}$ and $g(x)= \sqrt[n]{x^m}$ equal for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ operating for $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Some argue that they are not since their domain can be different. However, my argument is that since one form can be writtern as the other same restrictions can be applied. If the proposes logic is followed this means that:

$\sqrt[n]{x^m} \Rightarrow x^\frac{m}{n}$ holds only and the following does not

$\sqrt[n]{x^m} \iff x^\frac{m}{n}$. I'd like to hear some opinions

Comment: In order to answer this, we will need the definitions of the two functions.  I would say: for complex numbers $x$ and integers $m,n$ with $n \ne 0$, the two have the same meaning.  If you want some other versions of the functions, you will need to supply the definitions.

Comment: @GEdgar adding them now

Comment: You still haven't provided definitions of either function. Furthermore, logical connectives ($\implies$ and $\iff$) usually operate on truth values, so your statements need explanation. One thing to consider is what are $(-1)^{\frac22}$ and $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$.

Comment: @robjohn I wholeheartedly agree with you. However, this is how the question was stated in a particular book I found, no further explanations. I cannot provide any further definitions, because they would be mine and not of the exercise, thus making this question moot. I personally find this question largely incomplete on the same basis as your comment.  Now, as for the last part, by restricting to the properties of real numbers, both should and can be simplified into $|-1|=1$ since both statements are fundamentally the same

Comment: $\frac22=1$; so are you saying that $(-1)^1=1$?

Comment: @robjohn what if we write it as $((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{2}=1$? Or what if we write it as $((-1)^\frac{1}{2})^2$ which is not defined in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Those are obviously different things (not writing the same thing in two different ways). What about them? The first is $g$, the second has nothing to do with the question.